# Android: store image in database or drawable

Tags: android

In my app, there may be more than thousand of small image/ icon
and they will be display in views inside the list view or grid view

While I am wondering how the data should be store
1. covert to the string array and store in the database.
2. in the drawable folder (and how should the path store in the database?)
3. other better method?

Comment: Will they be downloaded or preloaded with the apk?

Comment: they are preloaded with the apk

Comment: if they are preloaded with the apk, there is probably an integer reference in `R`. Store that integer in your db.

Comment: may i know how could I get that integer? I just know how to get it by using R.drawable.image_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A drawable resource is a general concept for a graphic that can be drawn to the screen and which you can retrieve with APIs such as `getDrawable(int)` or apply to another XML resource with attributes such as `android:drawable` and `android:icon`.

You should store the images in Drawable folder. The Drawable folder is pre-compiled. Which means that the images will be fetched much faster than from Database.

Comment: Oh, so I should convert the 1000 images with different dpi? I found android studio can just convert 1 single image in a time. and will this increase the size of app?